# how to add another value to the value attribute?

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

i am using fusion charts with php. Now i have two values of blood pressure systolic and dialic. I have to show them side by side in the chart and i am using FCF_Column3D.swf. Can you please tell me how to add the second value to the xml attribute in php file.
Thank you in advance
Ramsai

Comment: What do you currently have?  What have you tried?

Comment: i currently have $strXML.="<set name='".$row['ondate']."'value='".$row['systole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>"; and i tried $strXML.="<set name='' value='".$row['diastole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>";

Comment: It might be easier if you edit your question to include that text (if you indent each line by four spaces, it'll be formatted properly too!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramsai:

When you say you want to plot 2 data points for each date, then the data becomes multi-series data.

You cannot have XML like this:

```
<set name="date" value1="systolic_value" value2="diaolic_value" />
```

You need to use the `FCF_MS_Column3D.swf` chart for plotting multi-series data.

The syntax for multi-series data is:

```
<chart> 
   <categories>
      <category name='date-1' />
      <category name='date-2' />
      <category name='date-3' />
   </categories>

   <dataset seriesName='systolic'>
      <set value='1' />
      <set value='2'/>
      <set value='3' />
   </dataset>

   <dataset seriesName='diaolic'>
      <set value='1'/>
      <set value='2'/>
      <set value='3'/>
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

This should work for you very well.

For PHP:

```
$strXML = "<chart>";
$categories = "<categories>";
$systolic = "<dataset seriesName='systolic'>";
$diaolic = "<dataset seriesName='diaolic'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories .= "<category name='" . $row["ondate"] . "' />";
    $systolic .= "<set value='" . $row["systole_reading"] . "' />";
    $diaolic .= "<set value='" . $row["diastole_reading"] . "' />";
}
$strXML .= $categories . "</categories" . $systolic . "</dataset>" . $diaolic . "</dataset>" . "</chart>";

//$strXML now has the complete XML required to render the multi-series chart.
```

Comment: ok hrishikesh can give any idea how to do the same one with php because i am using same code with php. When i tried in php i am not getting any display

Comment: i tried it with your code but it is giving message nodata to display. what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Did you change the chart to a multiseries chart type? "No Data To Display" is shown when single series data is passed to multiseries charts, or vice versa.

Comment: is this the one you are saying echo renderChartHTML("FusionCharts/FCF_MSColumn3D.swf", "", $strXML, "BloodPressure", 850, 450,false);

Comment: i got the answer and it is working Thank you for your help and i replace chart with graph it is working but with chart it is not working

Comment: Since you're using FusionCharts Free, you should stick to <graph>. The <chart> element is used for the commercial versions of FusionCharts.

Comment: If your problem is solved, then please mark this answer as "Accepted". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Example from [fusioncharts.com](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#column-and-bar):

```
<chart yAxisName='Sales Figure' caption='Top 5 Sales Person' numberPrefix='$' showBorder='1' imageSave='1' imageSaveURL='http://www.fusioncharts.com/ExportHandlers/PHP/_FCExporter.php'>

    <set label='Alex' value='25000'  />

    <set label='Mark' value='35000' />

    <set label='David' value='42300' />

    <set label='Graham' value='35300' />

    <set label='John' value='31300' />


</chart>
```

Comment: you are right but i am trying to generate the same dynamically for example $strXML.="<set name='".$row['ondate']."'value='".$row['systole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>";
           $strXML.="<set name='' value='".$row['diastole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>";

Comment: what chart type? regular column 3d or stacked?

Comment: i am using this chart type FCF_Column3D.swf

Comment: instead of "name" use "label"

Comment: i used label but here from db i will get three values one is systolic second one is diaolic third one is the date. i want to display dates on xaxis and systolic and dialoc on y axis . here is my code part which displays the data.$strXML.="<set label='".$row['ondate']."'value='".$row['systole_reading']."'display value='".$row['diastole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>";
           //$strXML.="<set label='".$row['ondate']."' value='".$row['diastole_reading']."' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>";

Comment: When you're using FusionCharts Free, then 'name' is correct, rather than 'label'.